# JMSTranslationBundle extract translation key in Entity static function

Tags: php, symfony

I have a static function in an Entity which contains some translation keys in an array.

```
public static function aStaticFunction()
{
    return array(
        0 => 'a.translation.key',
        'another.translation.key',
    );
}
```

When I run extract command of JMSTranslationBundle, the translation keys are not extracted. How to make it detect and extract them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JMSTranslationBundle is not extracting translation keys from Entity. So, here is what I did:

Create a service and tag it with `jms_translation.file_visitor`:

```
acmecustom.translator.entity.extractor:
    class: Acme\CustomBundle\Translator\EntityExtractor
    tags:
        - { name: jms_translation.file_visitor }
```

And the extractor class (some lines/functions truncated):

```
<?php
namespace Acme\CustomBundle\Translator;

use JMS\TranslationBundle\Model\FileSource;
use JMS\TranslationBundle\Model\Message;
use JMS\TranslationBundle\Model\MessageCatalogue;
use JMS\TranslationBundle\Translation\Extractor\FileVisitorInterface;

class EntityExtractor implements FileVisitorInterface, \PHPParser_NodeVisitor
{
    private $traverser;
    private $catalogue;
    private $file;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->traverser = new \PHPParser_NodeTraverser();
        $this->traverser->addVisitor($this);
    }

    public function enterNode(\PHPParser_Node $node)
    {
        if (!$node instanceof \PHPParser_Node_Scalar_String) {
            return;
        }

        $id = $node->value;

        // ignore multiple dot without any string between them
        if (preg_match('/(\.\.|\.\.\.)/', $id)) {
            return;
        }

        // only extract dot-delimitted string such as "custom.entity.firstname"
        if (preg_match('/.*\./', $id)) {
            $domain = 'messages';
            $message = new Message($id, $domain);
            $message->addSource(new FileSource((string) $this->file, $node->getLine()));

            $this->catalogue->add($message);
        }
    }

    public function visitPhpFile(\SplFileInfo $file, MessageCatalogue $catalogue, array $ast)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->catalogue = $catalogue;

        // only extract from path/directory 'Entity'
        if ($this->file->getPathInfo()->getFilename() == 'Entity') {
            $this->traverser->traverse($ast);
        }
    }
}
```